# Need Save and New method in controller for save and new custom button

Tags: visualforce, controller, custom-button, save-and-new

I trying to add Save and new button at quote line item page editor level. But I'm stuck with ideas.

Controller:

```
    public PageReference save() {
        checkRecursive.run = false;

        refresh();
        for (QuoteLineItemWrapper quoteWrap: TotalquoteLineItems) {
            if (quoteWrap.quoteLineItem.DisCount_Amount__c > 0) {
                if (quoteWrap.subTotal != 0) {
                    Double variableONE = 100 - (((quoteWrap.subTotal - quoteWrap.quoteLineItem.DisCount_Amount__c) * 100) / quoteWrap.subTotal);
                    quoteWrap.quoteLineItem.Discount = variableONE;
                }
            }
        }
        List < QuoteLineItem > itemsToInsertOrUpdate = new List < QuoteLineItem > ();
        List < QuoteLineItem > ExiistingitemsToUpdate = new List < QuoteLineItem > ();

        for (QuoteLineItemWrapper itemWrapper: quoteLineItems) {
            itemsToInsertOrUpdate.add(itemWrapper.quoteLineItem);
        }
         for (QuoteLineItemWrapper itemWrapper: ExistingquoteLineItems) {
            ExiistingitemsToUpdate.add(itemWrapper.quoteLineItem);
        }


        String errorMsg;

        if (!itemsToInsertOrUpdate.isEmpty()) {

                            return null;
            }


            if (mode == 'Add' || mode == 'AMS')
                try {
                    insert itemsToInsertOrUpdate;
                    if(ExiistingitemsToUpdate!=null && ExiistingitemsToUpdate.size()>0){
                       update ExiistingitemsToUpdate;
                    }
                    MRsort();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                errorMsg = e.getMessage();               
            } else if (mode == 'Edit') {
                try {
                    update itemsToInsertOrUpdate;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    errorMsg = e.getMessage();
                }
            }
            if (mode != 'Edit') {
                errorMsg = updateTAC(errorMsg);
                //return null;
            }
        }
 if (errorMsg != null && errorMsg != '') {
            ErrorManager(errorMsg);
            //Apexpages.Message errMsg = new Apexpages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR , errorMsg);
            //Apexpages.addMessage(errMsg);
            return null;
        }
        return new PageReference('/' + quoteId);
    }
```

VF ppage:

```
<body onload="OnLoadQuantityModif();">           
<apex:form id="pageform" >

<apex:pageMessages escape="false" ></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:actionFunction name="sayHello" action="{!save}" rerender="out" status="myStatus"/>
 <apex:pageBlock id="pb" title="New Quote Line Items for {!quote.Name}">
 <font color="red"><apex:outputText value="{!strLeadMsg}"  /></font>
<!--            Add/Edit Products to this quote from {!priceBook.Name}-->
          <br/> 
            <br/>  
            <apex:pageblockbuttons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" rendered="{!IF(ISNULL( strAfficherSaveButton) ,false,true)}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save Multiple items" action="{!saveMultyplesitems}" rendered="{!IF(ISNULL(strAfficherMultipleButton) ,false,true)}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/><br/> <br/>


                <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save & New" id="saveAndNew"/>
                    <apex:param name="newAndSave" value="newAndSave" />
```

Here I did not copied the whole save method. **I'm not sure that I have to write a new method for save and new or I can just add some code in save method.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `save` method to your controller it will be used instead of the standard save method provided by the standard controller.

So whatever you want to happen when the user clicks *save* **you** will have to write.

After rereading I get what you are asking now:

You can add another method to use the current `save()` method then after that is finished executing have it do the additional code needed for the `new` part

```
public pagereference saveandnew(){
   save();
   //Do what you need to do to direct the user to the NEW record
   //not sure if it is the standard page you want to take them to or something in your current page
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

I wanted the user to redirect to custom page and this page have the products list ... where user selects the products and add to quote line item

Comment: @Gidy - great, simply add that code in what I gave you and you are on your way

Comment: public PageReference saveAndNew() {  
     
                 save();

            PageReference redirectPage = new PageReference('/' + quoteId);

            redirectPage.setRedirect(true);

            return redirectPage;

            return null;

            }
This the code I have added after your say. But it still returning to the quote page. Not to the products list page.